# Datatable AltEditor Mysql Guide

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatable, forum

I am new to using datatables and been trying to use an [alternative editor](https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor) for a project I'm working on. Thing is, there is little detail on its documentation on how to use for mysql data, it has some information about using with AJAX but I can't find example on how to connect to a mysql server to work on.

Basically if anyone knows how to connect alteditor to my mysql database, do inline add edit delete actions in the table and if possible teach me a way to make a row clickable and redirect other page, (this page will contain values of the row in a form). A tutorial would be nice.

Honestly I don't know if stackoverflow is the place to ask this but I'm desperate lol.